# Pug/Jade not compiling value for nonce attribute

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I need to use a nonce on script and style elements.

With pug I write:

```
script(nonce="some-nonce")
```

and it outputs:

```
<script nonce></script>
```

whereas I am expecting:

```
<script nonce="some-nonce"></script>
```

I am thinking of trying to edit the sourcecode of pug to fix this but this will be a lot of effort.

I have posted an [issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2899) on github about this but I was wondering if anyone knows of a solution or workaround?

Comment: For anyone with this issue, it could be that dev tools are not displaying the nonce despite it being there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does actually output the correct html. However, when using Google dev tools with inspect element, it will not show the nonce value - but if you view the page source, it will show it.

This is likely some sort of security measure.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/yPgVaZ), but no success (it worked as expected). Inspect the output of the Pen and see that the attribute is properly copied over:

```
<script nonce="some-nonce">console.log("test");</script>
```

Maybe this has to do with an out-of-date Pug version on your build system? If all else fails, you can always also just input plain HTML in Pug (see the CodePen for a demo of this workaround).

Comment: On my page (localhost) I inspect the source of the page and it shows the nonce. But when I inspect the elements, it is just 'nonce'. Also I ran npm test on pug after adding my own test for nonce, and it passed. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with pug, but something is stripping the nonce away on page load or something... An alternative to a nonce is to use a hash (this is for Content-Security=Policy), but that hasn't been working either!.... many hours without success here, thanks for attempting to help anyway.

Comment: nonce1 works, noncey works, just not nonce. However, I just realized it means 'number used once' and.... I used it on 2 style/script elements sooo.... wow I feel like an idiot, just testing now... oh, still not working.

Comment: I'm assuming you've read/tried the things listed [on the Google docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it)?

Comment: yes. I have had a lot of help from https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2369 too. I found out that nonce is not meant to be shown in inspect. I now have it mostly working, but have a few issues - one is that despite loading the inline css and applying it, I am getting console error messages from CSP for this.